# Having a "TypeError: datasheet.appendRow.setValues is not a function (line 14, file "Code")" appear when running a google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First off, this is not my code but is my co-workers.  I said id look at it and try to figure out the issue since she is busy.  The code is suppose to grab the information from the input page and pull it over to the data (test) page, meant to be a dummy page for the other workers doing an inventory count.  When i run the script it's giving a "TypeError: datasheet.appendRow.setValues is not a function (line 14, file "Code")" error.  Below is the code she made; if anyone can help with the error and let me know if there is any other glaring issue that would be much appreciated.

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Input"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test"); //Data Sheet
  
  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("B4").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B8").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B14").getValue()]];
  
   datasheet.appendRow.setValues(values);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply `setValues()` on `appendRow()`. Also `appendRow()` accepts a 1D array object `[]` but `values` is a `[[]]` array.

Try this instead:

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Input"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test"); //Data Sheet
  
  //Input Values
  var values = [formSS.getRange("B4").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B8").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B14").getValue()];
  
   datasheet.appendRow(values);
```

Please familiarize yourself with the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) and in particular with the following functions:

- [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)